Is groff ignoring `.nh` command?
For a man page written in POD (perlpod) I had the effect that the SYNOPSIS was left-adjusted on the text terminal, but the PostScript output (read: troff) adjusted the text to both borders.
So I tried to embed formatting commands in the POD source.
However, even when specifying .nh some words like "[--[no-]check-grace-logins]" were hyphenated at a minus.
That made me wonder whether the man -l command disobeys the .nh command.
The manual page for roff(7) says:

.nh       No hyphenation.

Here is the relevant part of the roff man page:
.\" ========================================================================
.\"
.IX Title "LDAP-USER-CHECK 8"
.TH LDAP-USER-CHECK 8 "2024-08-14" "0.0.0.0.20n" "System Administration"
.\" For nroff, turn off justification.  Always turn off hyphenation; it makes
.\" way too many mistakes in technical documents.
.if n .ad l
.nh
.SH "NAME"
ldap\-user\-check \- check LDAP account status
.SH "SYNOPSIS"
.IX Header "SYNOPSIS"
.\" BEGIN roff
.\" save adjustment, then left-adjust
.ds _A \n[.j]
.ad l
.\" save hyphenation, then disable
.ds _H \n[.hy]
.nh
.\" END roff
\&\fBldap-user-check\fR
[\fB\-\-account\-context=\fR\fIcontext\fR]
[\fB\-\-account\-filter=\fR\fIfilter\fR]
[\fB\-\-add\-notification\-bcc\-address=\fR\fIemail-spec\fR]...
[\fB\-\-add\-notification\-cc\-address=\fR\fIemail-spec\fR]...
[\fB\-\-default\-default\-ppolicy=\fR\fIdn\fR]
[\fB\-\-default\-language=\fR\fIlang\fR]
[\fB\-\-default\-notification\-email\-address=\fR\fIemail-spec\fR]...
[\fB\-\-ca\-certs\-path=\fR\fIpath\fR]
[\fB\-\-\fR[\fBno\-\fR]\fBcheck-auth-failure\fR]
[\fB\-\-\fR[\fBno\-\fR]\fBcheck-grace-logins\fR]
[\fB\-\-\fR[\fBno\-\fR]\fBcheck-inconsistent-accounts\fR]
[\fB\-\-\fR[\fBno\-\fR]\fBcheck-locked-accounts\fR]
[\fB\-\-\fR[\fBno\-\fR]\fBcheck-password-policy\fR]
[\fB\-\-\fR[\fBno\-\fR]\fBcheck-pp-override\fR]
[\fB\-\-\fR[\fBno\-\fR]\fBcheck-shadow-password\fR]
[\fB\-\-credentials\-file\-name=\fR\fIfilename\fR]
[\fB\-\-instance\-string=\fR\fIinstance\fR]
[\fB\-\-ldap\-size\-limit=\fR\fInumber\fR]
\&\fB\-\-ldap\-suffix=\fR\fIsuffix\fR
[\fB\-\-ldap\-time\-limit=\fR\fInumber\fR]
\&\fB\-\-ldap\-uri=\fR\fI\s-1URI\s0\fR
\&\fB\-\-notification\-template=\fR\fIfilename\fR
[\fB\-\-override\-default\-ppolicy=\fR\fIdn\fR]
[\fB\-\-override\-expiration\-warning\-time=\fR\fInumber\fR]
[\fB\-\-override\-from\-email\-address=\fR\fIemail-spec\fR]
[\fB\-\-override\-notification\-email\-address=\fR\fIemail-spec\fR]...
[\fB\-\-ppolicy\-context=\fR\fIcontext\fR]
[\fB\-\-set\-notification\-reply\-to\-address=\fR\fIemail-spec\fR]
[\fB\-\-verbosity=\fR\fIlevel\fR]
[\fB\-\-wrap\-template=\fR\fIlen\fR]
.\" BEGIN roff
.\" restore saved hyphenation and adjustment
.hy \*(_H
.ad \*(_A
.\" END roff
.SH "DESCRIPTION"
.IX Header "DESCRIPTION"

And here is what I see on a 80-character wide terminal:

WHen converting that manual page using groff -man -Tps the .nh seems to be ignored as well:

Programs being used are perl 5.18.2, groff-1.22, both from SLES12 SP5.

groff isn’t ignoring .nh, but its scope isn’t as comprehensive as you’re hoping.
.nh disables automatic hyphenation; words containing explicit hyphens (which is what check-auth-failure appears as to roff) are always eligible for breaking. This isn’t obvious from the documentation; but the “Manipulating hyphenation” section starts with

When filling, GNU troff hyphenates words as needed at user-specified and automatically determined hyphenation points.

and then proceeds to discuss, separately, user-specified and automatically determined hyphenation points.

Explicitly hyphenated words such as “mother-in-law” are eligible for breaking after each of their hyphens.

explains how explicit hyphens are handled.
Further down, in the discussion on automatic hyphenation, .nh is documented as a request to

Disable automatic hyphenation; i.e., set the hyphenation mode to 0 (see above).

To avoid unwanted explicit hyphenation in command keywords, use hyphen-minus symbols instead of “regular” hyphens:
[\fB\-\-\fR[\fBno\-\fR]\fBcheck\-auth\-failure\fR]

To understand the difference between the two, see Hyphens, minus, and dashes in Debian man pages (the distinction isn’t Debian-specific).
Since you’re using pod2man, you’d have to get it to use hyphen-minus symbols for you. It does that in some instances, for example after =item; but I don’t know of a way to ask it to generate hyphen-minus symbols elsewhere. It might be worth filing an issue about this.

Two comments: (1) in the reference cited I could only find "Explicitly hyphenated words such as “mother-in-law” are eligible for breaking after each of their hyphens. ", but I cannot deduce from that that hyphenation will still happen when .nh is being used. Maybe improve the citation. (2) the man page was actually created by pod2man, so the suggested solution to put roff commands inside the words cannot be done. But agreed, I did not tell that in the question.

I’ve added some explanation of the documentation, hopefully that addresses (1). Regarding (2), it wasn’t clear to me whether you were manually post-processing pod2man’s output, or hoped for a solution applicable to pod2man as well. I’ve been looking for the latter but I don’t think there is one.

Not quite: I wasn't "post-processing" the output; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/78652338/6607497 for an explanation.
